# Why do I need an extra asInstanceOf

Tags: scala

I wrote this code

```
listOfClassNames.map{ className => 
  Try {
    GuiceInjector.getInstance(Class.forName(className)).asInstanceOf[BaseClass]
  } recover {
    case _ => Option.empty[(String, BaseClass)]
  } match {
    case Success(bc) => Some((className, bc))
    case _ => Option.empty[(String, BaseClass)]
  }
}
```

The above code throws an error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[Option[(String, Object)]]
[error]  required: List[Option[(String, BaseClass)]]
```

Now if I change the code to

```
listOfClassNames.map{ className => 
  Try {
    GuiceInjector.getInstance(Class.forName(className)).asInstanceOf[BaseClass]
  } recover {
    case _ => Option.empty[(String, BaseClass)]
  } match {
    case Success(bc) => Some((className, bc.asInstanceOf[BaseClass]))
    case _ => Option.empty[(String, BaseClass)]
  }
}
```

Now it works. but according to me the second asInstanceOf is unnecessary because the first object itself was typecast. no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the call to `recover`. It's not needed anyway, because you process the error case inside `match`, but it messes up the types and correctness of your code.

Consider the types: `Try { /* ... */.asInstanceOf[BaseClass] }`
has type `Try[BaseClass]`.

Then `Try { /* ... */ } recover { case _ => Option.empty[(String, BaseClass)] }` is a `Try` of the common supertype of `BaseClass` and `Option[(String, BaseClass)]`, so it's `Try[AnyRef]`.

Thus inside the match in `case Success(bc) =>` this `bc` has type `AnyRef`, and at runtime it can be either an instance of `BaseClass` or `None`. If the original fetch of `BaseClass` from Guice fails, this `bc` is `None`, and you get a `ClassCastException` with the additional `isInstanceOf`.